# What is the definition of momentum when a mass distribution $\rho(r,t)$ is given?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

**This question is Edited after recieving comments.**

What is the definition of momentum when a mass distribution $\rho(r,t)$ is given?
Assuming a particle as a point mass we know the definition of momentum as $p = mv$.
 I need a definition where it is assumed that point masses are not present.

Comment: I don't know that they have other, more descriptive names.   In what context are you asking your question?   I mean, are you trying to derive the Navier Stokes equations or something like that?

Comment: @sigoldberg1: I want to know what is meant by momentum and momentum distribution, in this context.

Comment: maybe you'd be better off asking that. Or at least expand on your question to indicate why you're asking what you're asking and how momentum relates to it.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: please answer the edited part in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple masses the total momentum is
$$ p = \sum_i m_i v_i $$

If you have a continuum distribution then you can proceed like follows.
You divide the continuum into small boxes where each part of the box has approximately same mass and velocity (this assumes some kind of smoothness of the distribution). Then you can obtain whole momentum with the above formula. Now letting the box sizes go to zero you obtain integral

$$ p(t) = \int \rho(r, t) v(r, t) dr $$

Comment: @Marek: what do you call the quantity $\rho(r, t) v(r, t)$. What is $v(r, t)$ called ?

Comment: @Marek: How are $\rho(r, t), v(r, t)$ coupled if we were to describe the newtonian gravitation in a set of differential equations.

Comment: @Rajesh: I am not really sure about the terminology. But probably momentum distribution and velocity distribution. As for the coupling: everything works basically the same as for point masses. You can always carry out the above argument to transfer between continuum point of view and point masses point of view. So if you know the laws for point masses you should be able to proceed further yourself. If not then you should first learn about point masses before approaching continuum.

Comment: @Rajesh If it is a rigid body, this does not need a name since it is just constant velocity (rotation will cancel up). If it is fluid dynamics, this is just the flow. If it is elasticity, this is deformation velocity field or something like this, I don't recall it too well.

Comment: @mbq: thanks for the clarification. The rigidness or elasticity or nature of fluid dynamics are due to existence of various types of inter molecular forces or something similar.I am not interested in such things as i am not intending to describe any real world situation, my interests are only theoretical.

Comment: @mbq: Hence i am content with Marek's answer.

Comment: @Rajesh You wanted name for $v$ field, so here you are. Yet thinking about moving, unconstrained density field inevitably drives to fluid mechanics. And fluid is a broad word, from probability densities through water, sand, glaciers up to galaxies.

Comment: @mbq: What if $\rho(r,t)$ is zero in a region and $v(r,t)$ is not ! what would you call it then ?

Comment: @Rajesh: I would call it unphysical. And probably also mathematically inconsistent.

Comment: @Marek: That is why we should define $\rho(r,t)$ and $p(r,t) = \rho(r,t)v(r,t)$ as the basic entities called mass and momentum distributions respectively. In this way we can avoid calling something (which originated form a definition made in the theory itself) as unphysical.

Comment: @Rajesh:  For any fluid that is at all reasonable, $\rho$ and $\vec v$ have to satisfy the continuity equation $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} +  \nabla\cdot\left(\vec v \rho\right) = 0$, so they are not completely independent degrees of freedom anyway.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: in order to give initial conditions to a system, i guess they are. i mean at $t=0$

Comment: Sure, the initial values of the things are independent.  But their time evolution is completely not.

Comment: @Rajesh: actually it is often the case with physical equations that once you satisfy some condition (like ${\rm \mathbb div B} = 0$ for EM field) at initial time then the solution of an evolution equations will satisfy it at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-question:
What is the definition of **mass**, when a mass distribution given?

Strange question, isn't it?

Since you have the mass distribution you got to have the momentum **distribution** as well.

It is simply ρ*v.

Answer (score 0):

Motion of a non-point object can be described as a combination of translation (which only depends on the total mass of the object) and rotation (which depends on the mass distribution). Rotational momentum is defined as $\mathbf{L}= I \boldsymbol{\omega}$ where $I$ is a moment of inertia $I = \int_V \rho(\mathbf{r})\,d(\mathbf{r})^2 \, \mathrm{d}V\!(\mathbf{r})$

As you can see, the mass distribution defines the **rotational** momentum of a system.